# String a time function c++

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli

I need to take a time from a textbox there the time is written like 13:30.
I want to take two times and read them in minutes exampel: the first time is 13:30 and the second is 14:30 i want to tell them its 60 minutes can anyone help me It looks like this. i don't know maybe you can make a char array and just take the first two and then the last two but i don't quiet know how to make that

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2 < textBox2->Text->Length; i++)
{
    String^ SamtalsLengdtextBox2 = textBox2->Text;
    double samtalslengd2 = Convert::ToInt32(SamtalsLengdtextBox2));
    samtalslengd2 = samtalslengd2 * 60;
    textBox2->Text = Convert::ToString(samtalslengd2);
}

for (int u = 0; u < 2 < textBox3->Text->Length; u++)
{
    String^ SamtalsLengdtextBox3 = textBox3->Text;
    double samtalslengd3 = Convert::ToInt32(SamtalsLengdtextBox3));
}
```

Comment: [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) comes in handy for time conversions/calculations.

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Comment: who put this times into the textbox? cant you use the actual value instead of reading it from the text box as string? I guess somewhere it already has some date type that allows simple arithmetics

Comment: this is what i have written but it crashes the system... :/ https://gyazo.com/b8c69f10aa24d2e9d1298d02f1b0cdef

Comment: and i am going to take time and make a phone call that tells me how much it costs to speak for some time

Comment: @Rinaxe Put the minimal relevant code in your question please. A link in a comment isn't useful.

Comment: Could you give some explicit examples of inputs and expected outputs? I'm not sure what `i want to tell them its 60 minutes` means.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto first = DateTime::ParseExact(textBox1->Text, "hh:mm", Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);

auto second = DateTime::ParseExact(textBox2->Text, "hh:mm", Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);

auto timediff = first - second;

textBoxResult->Text = timediff->TotalMinutes->ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2 < textBox2->Text->Length; i++)
```

This structure (`x < y < z`) does not do what you think it does. Some languages support chained comparison operators, but for languages related to C (including C++, C++/CLI, and C#), you'll need to make it explicit: `(x < y) && (y < z)`.

We could re-write this with a better for loop, but I'm going to jump to the end. If you want to parse a duration, *[parse a duration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx?cs-lang=cpp)*.

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    String^ input = "13:30";
    TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan::Parse(input);

    Debug::WriteLine("The full value is {0}", duration);
    Debug::WriteLine("{0} minutes (total)", duration.TotalMinutes);
    Debug::WriteLine("{0} hours (total)", duration.TotalHours);
    Debug::WriteLine("The minutes portion is {0} minutes", duration.Minutes);
}
```

Output:

```
The full value is 13:30:00
810 minutes (total)
13.5 hours (total)
The minutes portion is 30 minutes
```

If you want to be more specific about how the [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) is parsed, you can also use one of the [`ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parseexact.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) methods. (For example, maybe "13:30" is supposed to be 13 minutes 30 seconds, not 13 hours 30 minutes.)